# How to find an intersphinx mapping for wx.CheckBoxState

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, wxpython

for my project documentation I use the [intersphinx mapping](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/es/stable/ext/intersphinx.html) to the wxpython documentation. That works fine so far but I don't succeed to get a link to [wx.CheckBoxState](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.CheckBoxState.enumeration.html#wx-checkboxstate). I tried to find information about that here and in other forums, but didn't find anything.

Here my code:

```
def my_meth( self, value, aStr ):
    """
    :param int value: This is my value
    :param str aStr: This is another value

    Description using

    - :py:class:`wx.CheckBoxState`
    - :py:class:`wx.CheckBoxState.enumeration`
    - :py:class:`wx.Validator`
    """
    self.my_var = value
    self.my_str = aStr
```

Running Sphinx produces

[image]

As you see links to "int", "str", "wx.Validator" work fine, but both attempts to find a link to wx.CheckBoxState didn't succeed.

There is still the hard coded way (a direct link to the page), but I would prefer the smart one (:py:class:...).

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance
Humbalan

By the way: I work with sphinx 1.7.5, python 3.7 and wxpython 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your intersphinx mapping configuration, you might need to adjust it.  Assuming it looks like this:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {
    'wx': ('https://docs.wxpython.org/', None),
}
```

You would then do this:

```
def my_meth( self, value, aStr ):
    """
    :param int value: This is my value
    :param str aStr: This is another value

    Description using

    - :ref:`wx.CheckBoxState`
    - :py:class:`wx.Validator`
    """
    self.my_var = value
    self.my_str = aStr
```

I assumed that [`:py:obj:`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#role-py:obj) would work as an object of unspecified type for `wx.CheckBoxState` and `wx.CheckBoxState.enumeration`, but it didn't.  I fell back to using `:ref:`, which worked for `wx.CheckBoxState` but not `wx.CheckBoxState.enumeration`, so I removed the latter. They seem to be the same target in the docs to me.

The style may be different, but I think that's the best you can hope for with the wxPython documentation out of the box.

You could try modifying your checkout of wxPython, modify the docs and possibly their source code until you get it to generate the link you want, then submit a pull request to them.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :ref: does not exactly what I would like to have, but it provides a link to the documentation and that is at the moment sufficient for me. You are right, the style is different: The theme I use (sphinxdoc) renders :ref: a "just another link" and :py:class: as "external link", they have different colors. Modifying the docs? Good idea, I will think about it.

Comment: I expected ``:any:`wx.CheckBoxState` `` to work, but it doesn't. http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-any